# Weird refractions appear when I use the Emission BSDF with Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, emission

Im working on a material for a visual effect i want to recreate. It divides the surface of the object into squares where some light up randomly (comparable to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=16&v=SSKVYP3jSLs).

### **Current State**

This is how it looks so far (Cycles Render):
[image]
It also randomly changes color and turns squares on/off like in the video.

### **How I made this**

My Material uses noise textures to determine the color of a square and whether it should be on or off. For the "on" squares i use an Emission BSDF mixed with a Translucent BSDF and for the "off" squares I use a Principled BSDF. You can find complete screenshots of the material here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8xSy.jpg

### **My Problem**

The problem is that on some frames some of the squares that should be turned off show weird refractions/artifacts (when rendered using cycles). Here is the same frame rendered using Eevee vs Cycles:

**Eevee** [image]
**Cycles** [image]

### What I tried so far

I've been debugging this for hours now. Steps I took (that did not solve the problem) include:

- Turning off the displacement
- Exchanging the Principled BSDF with a Diffuse BSDF
- Using a black/white squares instead of colorful ones

Exchanging the Emission BSDF nodes with other BSDFs did in fact solve the problme, but for the effect i want to create i nedd the Emission BSDF.

Thank you so much for your help!